# Interesting riddle about heights

Tags: probability, expected-value, puzzle

Choose a person randomly on the street, $X$. Let $N$ denote the random variable representing the number of people that you select randomly from the street before you find someone who's taller than $X$. What is $E[N]$?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Perhaps we would need the probability that a (randomly selected) person is taller than this $X$-person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly, the expected number is infinity.

Suppose that hights have a PDF $f_X$ and CDF $F_X$.

Given that the height of the first person is $x_0$, the probability of each other person (assuming iid) to be taller is $1-F_X(x_0)$. The number of people that should be measured before we find someone taller is geometric, so $E(N\vert X=x_0)=\tfrac{1}{1-F_X(x_0)}$.

Using total expectation, we get
$$E(N)=E(E(N\vert X))=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tfrac{f_x(x)dx}{1-F_X(x_0)}=-\ln (1-F_X(x))\vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\infty$$

A nice way to see it is to assume that $X$ has a uniform distribution over $(0,1)$. The calculation is similar to the above but with simple functions and the result is the same.
This assumption is "allowed" as in the question there is no assumption regarding the distribution of $X$, so it is possible to deduce that this should not matter, and in this case - we can test a simple distribution to get intuition.

Comment: This is right in the model case where there are infinitely many people on the street. If there are $n$ people with distinct heights, similar reasoning shows the answer is $H_n$, the $n$th harmonic number. (I interpret "taller than" liberally as "at least as tall". Otherwise, it's still infinite, because $X$ might be the tallest person.)